# New class or new .py Python

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I'm writing a Python script to check if a file is added to a folder with watchdog, that file is going to be added to a queue.

My idea is to add the filename to a txt, then either run a new class that watches the txt and then executes a line in cmd and start for example FME.

Is it the best way to write a new .py for every new program I want to open. For example one for FME and one for notepad.

I still want the watchdog class to go into the background.

- looking_for_files_and_adding_to_queue py
- looking_in_queue_for_the_next_in_line_and_direct_to_3_party py
- FME py
- Notepad py

and so on...

Or on all.py

```
class looking_for_files_and_adding_to_queue
class looking_in_queue_for_the_next_in_line_and_direct_to_3_party
class FME
class Notepad
```

Today my script looks like this:

```
import time
import sys
import os
import datetime
from watchdog.observers import Observer  
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.tif"]
    count_move = 0

    def process(self, event):
        if self.count_move == 1:
            # the file will be processed there
            folder = "P:\\03_auto\\Indata"
            indata = event.src_path

            #Makes a new folder in Utdata based on filename
            newfolder = os.path.join(folder[:11], str("Utdata\\orto"), event.src_path[18:29])
            if not os.path.exists(newfolder):
               os.makedirs(newfolder)
    
            #Logg and print start of FME
            print(time.strftime('%a %H:%M:%S') + ": FME " + event.src_path[18:] + " startats i FME.")
            log_file = open("P:\\03_auto\\log.txt", "a")
            log_file.write(time.strftime('%a %H:%M:%S') + ": FME " + event.src_path[18:] + " startats i FME.\n")
            log_file.close()
    
            #Starting and excequting FME
            var_fme = str('fme.exe "P:\\03_auto\\Script\\tiff_to_milti_jpg_tiff\\tif_to_multi-jpg-tiff.fmw" --SourceDataset_TIFF "') + indata + str('" --FEATURE_TYPES "" --DestDataset_JPEG "') + newfolder + str('" --DestDataset_JPEG_5 "') + newfolder + str('" --DestDataset_JPEG_4 "') + newfolder + str('" --DestDataset_GEOTIFF "') + newfolder + str('" --DestDataset_GEOTIFF_3 "') + newfolder + str('"')
            os.system(var_fme)

            #Logg and pring move file
            print(time.strftime('%a %H:%M:%S') + ": Flytt " + event.src_path[18:] + " har flyttats till" + newfolder + "\nTransformering klar\n")
            log_file = open("P:\\03_auto\\log.txt", "a")
            log_file.write(time.strftime('%a %H:%M:%S') + ": Flytt " + event.src_path[18:] + " har flyttats till" + newfolder + "\nTransformering klar\n\n")
            log_file.close()

            #Move org file to Utdata\orto
            file_move = newfolder + indata[17:]
            os.rename(indata, file_move)

            #Restets script
            self.count_move = 0
        else:
            #Logg and pring loadning file while transfering
            print(time.strftime('%a %H:%M:%S') + ": Laddar " + event.src_path[18:] + " startar inladdning.")
            log_file = open("P:\\03_auto\\log.txt", "a")
            log_file.write(time.strftime('%a %H:%M:%S') + ": Laddar " + event.src_path[18:] + " startar inladdning.\n")
            log_file.close()

            #Sets counter to 1 which enables the FME part
            self.count_move += 1


    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.process(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = "P:\\03_auto\\Indata"
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

Comment: What does FME stand for?

Comment: FME is a program. So via cmd I'm starting FME.exe. FME is a program that I can transform from anything to anything. For example I have a .TIF file that I'm resizing and changeing to .JPG and so on.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to automate some processing.
Open a program if a particular file is written inside a folder. Right?

Comment: Yes. I have a folder called Indata where I dump for example .TIF files or .TXT, then some type of a program, for example fme or notepad. But I want a queue system, so the programs don't start when an other program is useing it.

Comment: Now everything is in the same .py file. but maybe that's not the best way?

Comment: Putting multiple classes in one python module (.py file) is perfectly fine (it is in fact the recommended way). Python is not Java where you have to create a file for each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr keep everything in one file for now, split subsequently while refactoring when the file becomes huge.

---

Python does not force you split classes / functions into modules. We as programmers make that call for solely the purpose of readability and maintainability.

While refactoring I personally look at functions with more ~40 - 50 lines and files with ~ 1000 lines to split and try to keep closely related things together.

> high cohesion and low coupling.

is a characteristic feature of good software.

Also, since you seem to be starting out with this project I would recommend you to first concentrate on making a version that works, thereafter refactor it to improve code quality.

> premature optimization is the root of all evil.

---

I am assuming that you are looking for suggestions to improve code quality here, so here are a few things you might be also be interested in:

- follow pep8 standards: https://pep8.org
- make your functions / methods accept parameters instead of hardcoding them eg the path of the folder you are watching.
- make your program capable of resuming operations even after erroneous / abrupt termination: eg store state with a file or database
- instead of trying to implement a queue yourself use robust systems like rabbitmq or redis.
- write functions / methods that perform only one operation and do it well.

Comment: "make your functions / methods accept parameters instead of hardcoding them eg the path of the folder you are watching." How do you mean with that? To be able to know what folder the script should look you have to hardcore it?

Comment: "write functions / methods that perform only one operation and do it well." So in this instance I should have one def/class that looks in the folder, and one other class/def that excecute the script when  *.tif is found?

Comment: "keep everything in one file for now, split subsequently while refactoring when the file becomes huge." I want to expande the script now so it dose more things. Looks for *.tif, Exceute programs if *.tif found, looks in other folders if a file has been copied there then change name on it, check in a logfile if a certin chriteria has been filled then move files and so on. Is it wise to have all of that in one .py file? and put the excetuions in a queue?

Comment: I will be able to help more by looking at the code. The goal is to improve readability, because it directly effects maintainability of the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

This it how far I have done. Now I have to get the files from the que to FME

```
import time
import sys
import os
import datetime
import arrow

from watchdog.observers import Observer  
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
from shutil import copy

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items =[]

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.insert(0, item)

    def dequeue(self):
        self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def printqueue(self):
        i = 0
        for items in self.items:
            i += 1
            print(str(i) + ": " + items)

class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.tif","*.pdf"]
    q = Queue()

    def on_created(self, event):
        file_name = os.path.basename(event.src_path)
        file_type = file_name.split(".")[-1]
        file_path = "path"
        file_name_path = event.src_path
        endwith = file_name.endswith("_mosaic_group1.tif")
        new_folder = "C:\\FME_workdir\\"
        new_path = new_folder + file_name

        #create new temp folder for FME 
        if not os.path.exists(new_folder):
            os.makedirs(new_folder)

        #get tif file from project
        if file_name.endswith("_mosaic_group1.tif") and not             os.path.exists(new_path):
            print("Queue:")
            self.q.enqueue("[" + file_name + ", " + file_name_path + ", " + new_path + ", " + file_type + "]")
            self.q.printqueue()
            print("\n")
            #fme = Fme()
            #return fme.runfme(file_name, file_path, file_name_path)

        #copy file to FME folder    
            if not os.path.exists(new_path):
                copy(file_name_path, new_path)

        #get the PDF report        
        elif file_name.endswith("_report.pdf") and "1_initial" in file_name_path:
            pdf_path = os.path.dirname(file_name_path)
            pdf_path_new_path = "\\".join(pdf_path.split("\\")[:3])
            pdf_path_new_dir = "\\".join(pdf_path.split("\\")[5:6])
            date_now = str(time.strftime("%y%m%d"))
            pdf_new_path = pdf_path_new_path + "\\03_leverans\\" + pdf_path_new_dir + "_" + date_now
            pdf_new_path_filename = pdf_new_path + "\\" + file_name

            if not os.path.exists(pdf_new_path):
                os.makedirs(pdf_new_path)

            copy(file_name_path, pdf_new_path_filename)

        #put inte que system
            self.q.enqueue("[" + file_name + ", " + file_name_path + ", " + pdf_new_path + ", " + file_type + "]")
            self.q.printqueue()

class Fme:
    def runfme(self, file_name, file_path, file_name_path):
        print("FME: " + self.file_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = "P:\\"
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    print("stop")

    observer.join()

    input('Press ENTER to exit')
```